# How can I move a website from Drupal to WordPress without affecting the Google ranking

Tags: seo, wordpress, drupal, migration, transfer

How can I move a website from Drupal to WordPress without affecting the Google ranking?

The issue is that my client is already on the first page on Google, they are moving their site from Drupal to lovely WordPress and don't want to lose their top ranking.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this? I am new to this so would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not care which backend you use.

If you keep exactly the same **content**, **frontend** (i.e., same HTML, CSS, JS etc.) and **URLs**, search engines wouldn’t even notice that you switched to a different system.

While such a migration (without content/frontend/URL changes) would be ideal, it’s not necessary. The most important things are that you migrate all your content (without changing/restructuring too much) and keep all your URLs. If keeping the URLs is not possible, you should at least redirect them (with [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm sure I will be back with yet more questions but what's a girl to do who is new to SEO.

Comment: In fact can you briefly explain 301's please.

Comment: @ClareToolis: Did you read the linked Wikipedia article? It’s for permanently redirecting a URL to another URL. Example: This short share URL [`/q/78659/17633`](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/78659/17633) 301-redirects to the longer URL of your question [`/questions/78659/how-can-i-move-a-website-from-drupal-to-wordpress-without-affecting-the-google-r`](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78659/how-can-i-move-a-website-from-drupal-to-wordpress-without-affecting-the-google-r).